# How to persist queues and stacks to database

Tags: mysql, sql, serialization, data-structures

I have a stack data structure in memory. How would I persist this data to a database. I am open to any format json, xml or proprietary format. Once, it is serialized and persisted I need a way to deserialize it and store in memory. I was thinking I could use a normal JSON array to store but wanted to ask to see if there are better ideas on this.

Comment: Does your app or others need to query the queue/stacks while they are stored in database? If yes, binary format would prevent querying.

Comment: My app will query the queue. I think you're right. I'll try your way and Davide. I'll see which one works best.

Answer (score 2):

A stack is simply an ordered sequence of items.

You can store it in any database all the items in a table with an added column to mantain the order.

For example if you need to store a Person, with name and surname you can use the table

```
 Field     Type
 ---------------
 name      varchar
 surname   varchar
 position  int
```

You can retrieve the elements in the same order with a query like

```
 select name, surname from persons order by position
```

Then you can build your stack inserting all the items.

---

Don't store marshalled data in json format in a text field (varchar or longtext). If you really need to handle json data you can use the new [json datatype](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html) available from MySql 5.7.8:

> As of MySQL 5.7.8, MySQL supports a native JSON data type that enables efficient access to data in JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) documents. The JSON data type provides these advantages over storing JSON-format strings in a string column:
>
> Automatic validation of JSON documents stored in JSON columns. Invalid documents produce an error.
>
> Optimized storage format. JSON documents stored in JSON columns are converted to an internal format that permits quick read access to document elements. When the server later must read a JSON value stored in this binary format, the value need not be parsed from a text representation. The binary format is structured to enable the server to look up subobjects or nested values directly by key or array index without reading all values before or after them in the document.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches.

**Approach 1** If you don't need to access the individual elements in the queue/stack (you always load them altogether), then you can just store the serialized copy of your queue/stack.  Or alternatively, if the queue/stack (or the element of it) is complicated enough, you can marshal it into a XML or JSON string.  In both cases, you can then store the string into a DB column (probably in the `longtext` datatype).  When you need the queue/stack, you read the string from DB and then deserialize or unmarshall it back to a Java queue/stack.

For JSON, you can use GSON (`com.google.gson.Gson` and friends); for XML, you can use JAXB (`javax.xml.bind.JABContext` and friends)

**Approach 2** If you need to access the individual elements (e.g. they would form entity relations with some other entities), then you should map your queue/stack (being a collection) into individual rows in some DB table.  Hibernate would be a good tool to do that.  Google for "hibernate mapping collection"

Comment: For approach 2: You need at least to add a column position to mantain the insertion order. Storing the items without that information can change the order of the rebuild stack from the database. Additionally using a framework like hibernate only because you are not able to create a stack manually is a very bad approach.